# Python :: remove all occurrences until first space

Tags: python, string

how do I remove all occurrences in a string up to the first space, so that:

```
strings = ["1234 zoocore", "4356 00's punk"]
```

becomes:    `["zoocore", "00's punk"]` ?

I have tried regex:

```
for s in strings:
    new_s = re.sub(r'\d+','', s)
```

but that erases `00'` as well, which I don't want.

Comment: from `help(re)`:   _"`\A` Matches only at the start of the string."_ might be helpful... so I believe `"\A.*\s"` would match _the beginning of the string, any characters until the first whitespace._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `maxsplit` parameter:

```
>>> strings = ["1234 zoocore", "4356 00's punk"]
>>> [s.split(None, 1)[1] for s in strings]
['zoocore', "00's punk"]
```

If you have strings that  don't contain space you can use `-1` as index:

```
>>> strings = ["1234 zoocore", "4356 00's punk", "rock"]
>>> [s.split(None, 1)[-1] for s in strings]
['zoocore', "00's punk", 'rock']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you didn't anchor the match at the start of the string and that you didn't include the space. Here's a fixed version:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'^\d* ', '', s) for s in strings]
['zoocore', "00's punk"]
```

And just another way, finding the space (if any) and then slicing the string.

```
>>> strings = ["1234 zoocore", "4356 00's punk", "rock"]
>>> [s[s.find(' ') + 1:] for s in strings]
['zoocore', "00's punk", 'rock']
```